# Homology of Generalized Hyperbola

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Consider $H\le R^{a+b}$ defined by $$H = \{x\mid x_1^2+\cdots+x_a^2-x_{a+1}^2-\cdots-x_{a+b}^2=1\}$$ with some $b\ge 1$. This is a kind of 'generalized parabola' although I find it impossible to concieve in $\ge 4$ dimensions. I am trying to find the homology of this space. My idea was to try and integrate the Mayer–Vietoris sequence with induction on something, $b$ perhaps, to reduce the problem to a simpler one. However even if we take the simplest non-trivial case, $b=1$, this still seems remarkably impregnable.

Comment: Here's a way to "see off" the topology of $H$: Consider the slice $x_{a+1} = \cdots = x_{a+b} = 0$. This intersects $H$ in an $a$-sphere $S : x_1^2 + \cdots + x_a^2 = 1$. The $b$-dimensional hyperplane $x_1 = \cdots = x_a = 0$ is the "axis" $A$ of $H$ (notice that it doesn't intersect $H$).

Comment: For any point $p \in S$, there is a unique $b+1$-dimensional hyperplane which passes through $A$ and $p$, and intersects $H$ in a $b$-dimensional subspace of $H$ passing through $p$ (this is a projection of $A$ to $H$ if you want, so homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^b$). This should describe the (trivial) foliation of $H$ into $b$-submanifolds homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^b$, with transversal $S$, therefore settling that $H \cong \Bbb R^b \times S$, which deformation retracts to the $a$-sphere $S$.

Comment: You are telling me that $H\cong \mathbb{R}^b\times S^a$!? Surely this is false. I.e. when $a= b =1$ We have a hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ which is not even path connected.

Comment: Hah, thanks for catching that. $S$ is not an $a$-sphere, it's an $(a-1)$-sphere, was the semi-typo. It's homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^b \times S^{a-1}$.